# How can I access "visual voicemail" without closed-source apps on GrapheneOS?

Tags: applications, open-source, voicemail

Is there an open-source dialer or other application that allows access to PIN-protected voicemail messages? I don't want to have to call my voicemail. I am running GrapheneOS.

Comment: As far as I know there is not standardized access to voicemail systems via IP, therefore each app is carrier specific and carriers usually don't provide their apps as open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your phone? On CalyxOS and GrapheneOS there is a built-in Visual voicemail option in the default dialer but this won't work for every carriers.

> If you are having issues with Visual Voicemail, please be aware that AT&T USA users are unable to use this feature currently due to a lack of AOSP support. Other carriers are done on a best effort basis. We would suggest using Google Dialer with sandboxed Google Play if you are unable to get this feature working.
> https://grapheneos.org/usage#carrier-functionality

Answer (score 0):

Voicemail can kick in when you havent answered your phone or when the signal strength is too low and your phone cant connect to the network.  The latter is not going to work if you are relying on an app.

I havent seen any carrier provide any interface to their system, which appears to be different for different carriers.  Also, down under, they charge you extra to access voicemail, even when you have an expensive package deal.  They are not going to give up that money.

Comment: How does Google's "Visual Voicemail" work then?

Comment: @legacy-code-dev Is that Visual Voicemail an app (please provide link)? If I search for this term I only get results that are related to iPhones...